# Import all projects from gitlab 11 to gitlab 14

Tags: gitlab, migration

I've just created a brand new instance of Gitlab v.14.

I need to import all my projects (more than 100) from the old gitlab 11 to the new gitlab 14.

Do you have any suggestion or experience?

Answer (score 0):

GitLab 14.x cannot import projects *exported* by GitLab 11.x (see [version compatibility requirements](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/settings/import_export.html#12x).) Though you don't necessarily need to export your projects to import them to GitLab (as I'll suggest below).

Ideally, you should follow the [upgrade path](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/update/#upgrade-paths) then [migrate the two instances as a whole](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/import/index.html#migrate-between-two-self-managed-gitlab-instances).

But if you must do this by creating a new GitLab instance without being on the same version, there might be a few ways to do this.

### Group import

If you upgrade your original GitLab instance to at least version 13.7, you can use the [group migration tool](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/import/index.html).

### Project imports

If you can't upgrade your original instance, the easier way to import your projects is to have both instances running and [import projects by URL](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/import/repo_by_url.html). You don't need to export each project first.

### Import automation

If you have GitLab Premium or Ultimate, you can use [import automation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/import/index.html#automate-group-and-project-import).

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think that you can't import repositories from Group Migration Tool.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding projects, [GitLab 15.0](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/05/22/gitlab-15-0-released/#migration-support-for-project-releases-milestones) (May 2022) allows for a more complete import

> ### Migration support for project releases milestones
>
> We continue to add support for more release metadata to [GitLab migration](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/import/).
>
> In GitLab 15.0, we’ve added [project releases milestone](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/releases/#associate-milestones-with-a-release).
> This metadata will help you migrate more of the release data without needing to manually copy over missing release attributes.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/import/#migrated-resources) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/339422).

That will apply to your next migration (from your current instance to a new GitLab 15 one).

---

[GitLab 15.8](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/01/22/gitlab-15-8-released/#migrating-gitlab-projects-by-direct-transfer-beta) (January 2023) further improves the process:

> ### Migrating GitLab projects by direct transfer Beta
>
> Now, you can migrate group and project resources together when using direct transfer.
>
> You can use direct transfers to migrate between GitLab instances or within the same GitLab instance.
>
> Migrating projects when [migrating groups using direct transfer](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/import/#migrate-groups-by-direct-transfer-recommended) is a major improvement from migrating groups and projects using [file exports](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/settings/import_export.html) because:
>
> - You don’t need to manually export each project to a file and then import all those export files to a new location.
>   Now all projects within a top-level group are migrated automatically, making your work more efficient.
> - When migrating from self-managed GitLab to GitLab.com, user associations (such as comment author) are not changed to the user who is importing the projects.
>   Migration using direct transfer maps users and their contributions correctly, provided [a few conditions are met](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/import/#preparation).
>
> This feature is available on GitLab.com. You can migrate from a self-managed GitLab to GitLab.com right now!
>
> To enable it on GitLab self-managed instances, see the linked documentation.
>
> Learn more about migrating GitLab projects by direct transfer Beta and what’s coming next in our recent [blog post](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2023/01/18/try-out-new-way-to-migrate-projects/).
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/15_8/groups-import-with-projects.png -- Migrating GitLab projects by direct transfer Beta]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/import/#migrate-groups-by-direct-transfer-recommended) and [Epic](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/9285).

---

[GitLab 16.3](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/08/22/gitlab-16-3-released/#configurable-import-limits-available-in-application-settings) (August 2023) adds:

> ### Configurable import limits available in application settings
>
> Hardcoded limits exist for both migration by direct transfer and by importing export files.
>
> In this release, we’ve made some of these limits configurable in application settings to allow self-managed GitLab administrators to adjust them according to their needs:
>
> - [Maximum relation size that can be downloaded from the source instance in direct transfer](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/settings/account_and_limit_settings.html#maximum-download-file-size-for-imports-by-direct-transfer).
>   Previously hard-coded at 5 GB. On GitLab.com, we’ve set this limit to 5 GB.
> - [Maximum size of a remote import file that can be downloaded from remote Object Storages (such as AWS S3)](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/settings/account_and_limit_settings.html#maximum-remote-file-size-for-imports).
>   Previously hard-coded at 10 GB. On GitLab.com, we’ve set this limit to 10 GB.
>
> We’ve also added a new [maximum decompressed file size for imported archives](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/settings/account_and_limit_settings.html#maximum-decompressed-file-size-for-imported-archives) application setting, which replaces the `validate_import_decompressed_archive_size` feature flag. This limit was hardcoded to 10 GB. On GitLab.com, we’ve set this limit to 25
> GB.
>
> With these new application settings, both self-managed GitLab and GitLab.com administrators can adjust these limits as needed.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/import/index.html#limits), [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/384976) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/387932).

---

The import status and failed import are now clearer:

See [GitLab 16.7](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/12/21/gitlab-16-7-released/#comprehensive-results-of-imports-by-direct-transfer) (December 2023)

> ### Comprehensive results of imports by direct transfer
>
> Knowing how crucial for our users is to understand the results of the import process, in this milestone we further improved on information presented for imports by direct transfer. We now display import status badges next to GitLab groups and projects on:
>
> - The [page where you can select groups and projects to import](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/import/index.html#select-the-groups-and-projects-to-import).
> - The [page listing imported groups and projects](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/import/index.html#group-import-history).
>
> The import status badges are:
>
> - **Not started**
> - **Pending**
> - **Importing**
> - **Failed**
> - **Timeout**
> - **Cancelled**
> - **Complete**
> - **Partially completed**
>
> The **Partially completed badge** was added in this release and identifies a completed import process that has some items (such as merge requests or issues) not imported.
>
> Groups that an import process was started for have a **View details** link that shows imported subgroups and projects for that particular group. From there, you can see the list of items that couldn’t be imported (if any) by clicking a **See failures** link. **See failures** was [released in the last release](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/11/16/gitlab-16-6-released/#comprehensive-list-of-items-that-failed-to-be-imported).
>
> In this milestone we also improved navigation with the breadcrumbs between those pages.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/import/#review-results-of-the-import) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/394727).

---

[GitLab 16.9](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2024/02/15/gitlab-16-9-released/#show-import-stats-for-direct-transfer) (February 2024) includes:

> ### Show import stats for direct transfer
>
> Completed migrations of GitLab groups and projects by direct transfer have displayed badges (**Complete**, **Partially completed**, and **Failed**) to inform users about the general end result of the migration. Users could also access a list of items that were not imported, by clicking on the **See failures** link.
>
> However, for a partially-imported project, there was no quick way to understand how many items of each type were successfully imported and how many were not.
>
> In this release, we added import results statistics for groups and projects. To access the statistics, select the **Details** link on the direct transfer history page.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/import/index.html#review-results-of-the-import) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/437874).